# Is 'format' an invalid parameter to to_datetime in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, time-series

I have the following code as below to create a 'Date' column with date values parsed from another column 'Open Time', which contains a both date and time eg 1/1/2022 10:40:00

The code is as follows:

```
# create date column 
df.insert(3,"Date",pd.to_datetime(df["Open Time"]).dt.date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
```

However, the following error is generated upon running

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\JK\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11644/253220935.py in <module>
      1 # create date column
----> 2 df.insert(3,"Date",pd.to_datetime(df["Open Time"]).dt.date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
      3 df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

TypeError: insert() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'
```

I found that without the format parameter, the code can run. However, my dates get jumbled up in the output (the dates with days 2nd to 12th are swopped incorrectly with the months). Hence, I really want to fix this error to see if it will resolve the jumbling of day and month issue. Hope can get some advice here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `format` parameter is misplaced. Use:

```
df.insert(3, "Date", pd.to_datetime(df["Open Time"], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date)
```

Comment: thanks for the correction, mozway. After replacing the code, a different error pops up.

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
......
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
----> 2 df.insert(3, "Date", pd.to_datetime(df["Open Time"], format='%d/%m/%Y').dt.date)
      3 df["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
....

ValueError: unconverted data remains:  10:38:00

Comment: Not sure if this error statement meant that there is this string '10:38:00' somewhere in the data?

Comment: your solution did solve the type error even though a different error surfaced (probably due to data or other parts of the script). Hence I have voted it as a solution.